# Robocopy copia ficheros de local a servidor

Tags: windows, windows10, powershell, permisos

Cuando realizo copias del servidor al equipo local no tengo ningún problema de accesos ya que, en el equipo local, tengo las credenciales del servidor añadidas en el administrador de credenciales de windows.

El problema viene cuando intento copiar carpetas/ficheros de local al servidor donde obtengo el siguiente error:

**2020/11/16 19:22:21 ERROR 5 (0x00000005) Obteniendo acceso al directorio de destino \192.168.1.249\pruebas

Acceso denegado.**

El comando que estoy utilizando es el siguiente:

```
$destination = "\\192.168.1.249\pruebas\"
$source = "D:\Documentos\robocopy\"
robocopy $source $destination /E /Z /R:10 /W:15
```

¿Dónde puede estar el error y cómo podría solucionarlo?

Comment: Parece que, o bien el servidor no tiene esa carpeta compartida, o que el usuario que usas no dispone de permisos de escritura.

Comment: Gracias por su comentario, acabo de encontrar el error y es debido a que en el uso compartido de la carpeta estaba limitando a 1 usuario y al estar usandose tanto en el servidor como en local no me dejaba acceder...